# How to add carousel to text elements in a grid by using only bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, frontend, carousel, bootstrap-5

I want to add carousal to this part of my code by only using **Bootstrap 5**. But this is what I have got (*they arent moving*):
[image: carousal]

---

This is my `HTML` code:

```
<div class="container px-4">
  <div class="row gx-5">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="p-5 bg-danger">
        <h5>
          Online Meeting
        </h5>
        <p>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="p-5 bg-danger">
        <h5>
          Best Networking
        </h5>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="p-5 bg-danger">
        <h5>
          Best Education
        </h5>
        <p>
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I am expected to use only **Bootstrap** - not other plugins such as *Owl Carousel*. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: you are missing .carousel classes. be sure to check docs, [here]https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#how-it-works)

Comment: Hi, before asking for help, be sure to check specific documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to each div -> `class="carousel-item"` and main div `class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel"` . Before asking check docs. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#how-it-works